# Laravel storing tmp filename in database

Tags: php, laravel

The upload script is working, the file also gets saved by the correct/desired name. However, while storing data in database, it stores .tmp filename instead

Controller code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'featured_image' =>'image|max:1999'
    ]);

    $post = new Post;

    if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
        $image = $request->file('featured_image');
        // dd($image);

        $filename = time(). '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // dd($filename);
        $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        // dd($location);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);
        // dd($image);

        $post->image = $filename;

        // dd($post);
    }

    auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(request(['title', 'body', 'featured_image']))
    );

    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

It's storing file name as `C:\xampp\tmp\phpD837.tmp`. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it store/update the actual `.tmp` filename? Because What I see here is: you don't save with `$post->save()`

Comment: Don't be lazy copy the code instead of adding a picture !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new `Post` with your correct image filename:

```
$post = new Post;
....
$post->image = $filename;
```

But then when you save to the database, you do not use that `$post` data at all:

```
auth()->user()->publish(
    new Post(request(['title', 'body', 'featured_image']))
);
```

So basically you create another new `Post` with the POSTed data, which includes the temp PHP filename, ignoring the first `Post` which has the filename you want.

Try something like:

```
$post = new Post;
....
$post->image = $filename;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->body  = $request->body;

auth()->user()->publish($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the 'image' column in my $fillable variable. In Model Post.php

```
protected $table = "posts";

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'image', //delete if exists
    'content'
];
```